# How can my (C++) code tell if it is being compiled inside Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Background: I develop in Eclipse, and invoke the makfile from Hudson for nightly builds. I would like different values for some `#ifdef`s depending on whether the code is built in Eclipse or externally from the makefile.

So, something like `#ifdef _Eclipse_` would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to pollute your code like that? (Clarification: I mean write Eclipse- or Hudson-specific code. Just pick a better macro name and define that in Eclipse or Hudson.)

I'd make seperate targets or otherwise change the build file to pass a -DECLIPSE or -DHUDSON to the preprocessor.

Or pass a parameter to make:
Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Build command: `make CFLAGS+=-DECLIPSE`

Edit: I cannot get += to work from the command line. You might want to try, inside the Makefile:

```
  ifeq ($(BUILT_BY), eclipse)
    CFLAGS += -D_Eclipse_
    CXXFLAGS += -D_Eclipse_
  endif
```

and modify eclipse's 'make command' as such: `make BUILT_BY=eclipse`

Comment: plus one for "pollute" - post another comment and I will plus one that too. That's exactly how I feel about it too.

And also you other suggestions  -I didn't know how to pass -D parameters to make, but never thought of omitting them by default by declaring them only in exlipse.

Thnaks

Answer (score 3):

You can yourself define `_Eclipse_` or something else for the build you run on Eclipse.

Comment: Yikes! The bleedin' obvious staring me in the face!!

But it's like one of those coding things where you have to think of the negative case.

That will work.  Thanks, Amit

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, folks, but his question is answered by another ...

[Passing C/C++ #defines to makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039643/passing-c-c-defines-to-makefile/2105932#2105932)