# Resolving ifdefs when compiling a shared library

Tags: c++, c, templates, makefile, shared-libraries

I'm working on a shared library that has some header files which contain function templates like:

```
#ifdef somecompilerflag
#define FUNCTION functionA
#else
#define FUNCTION functionB
#endif

void FUNCTION( ... );
```

The `somecompilerflag` is something defined when compiling *my* library. However, if someone else wants to link to this library, I don't want them to have to pick up my compiler flags when including these header files. Is there a way to resolve these `#ifdefs` when compiling the library, so that a resulting header file would look something like:

```
void functionA( ... );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an answer here earlier that alluded to this approach, which is if the `somecompilerflag` is defined, when "compiling" the header file (actually copying to another directory) insert `#define somecompilerflag` at the top of the file. For the makefile, something along the lines of:

```
ifeq ($(somecompilerflag),-Dsomecompilerflag)
    sed '1 i\#define somecompilerflag' $(header) > headersDir/$(header)
else
    cp $(header) headersDir/$(header)
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting Linux&co, there's something called "pkg-config", which is a framework to retrieve compiler and linker settings for a particular installed library. Another option is to write a sed script to convert a template header file into the correct version for installing. I'd even do so before compiling the library, because then you could assure that the same header is used while compiling and that it fits.

Answer (score 0):

You can add defines to your Makefile. You can look here on how to do that: [Passing C/C++ #defines to makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039643/passing-c-c-defines-to-makefile)

Comment: I know how to get _my_ code to get the defines in, but I want _other_ codes not to need to.

Answer (score 0):

What about changing your first pre-processor directive to be #ifndef instead of #ifdef?

This way, if the flag is not set, FUNCTION would resolve to functionA, which sounds like what you want.

If you want to take it further and make it so that other people don't even see your pre-processor directives, you could simply run your code through the pre-processor and hand people the resulting output.

Comment: I want the user to be able to chose `functionA` or `functionB` when compiling the library, but not need to worry about my compiler flags after that. Both are equally likely. I also want to give people the code for the library to compile, not just the compiled version (which may be system-specific).