# Passing parameter to Makefile to change compiled code

Tags: c++, makefile, shared-libraries

I'm new to make. I am working on a C++ shared library, and I want it to have the option to compile with or without support for a certain feature (block of code). In other words, how do I enable the user to choose whether or not to compile the library with that feature by (maybe) passing a parameter to the make command?

For example, I need the user to be able to do this:

```
make --with-feature-x
```

How do I do this? Do I need to write a configure file for example? Or can I do this directly within my Makefile?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039643/passing-c-c-defines-to-makefile might help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the following way should work.  You define an environment variable when running `make`. In the Makefile, you check the status of the environment variable. Depending on the status, you define the options that will be passed to g++ when compiling the code. g++ Uses the options in the preprocessing phase to decide what to include in the file (e.g. source.cpp).

### The command

```
make FEATURE=1
```

### Makefile

```
ifeq ($(FEATURE), 1)  #at this point, the makefile checks if FEATURE is enabled
OPTS = -DINCLUDE_FEATURE #variable passed to g++
endif

object:
  g++ $(OPTS) source.cpp -o executable //OPTS may contain -DINCLUDE_FEATURE
```

### source.cpp

```
#ifdef INCLUDE_FEATURE 
#include feature.h

//functions that get compiled when feature is enabled
void FeatureFunction1() {
 //blah
}

void FeatureFunction2() {
 //blah
}

#endif
```

To check if FEATURE is passed in or not (as any value):

```
ifdef FEATURE
  #do something based on it
else
  # feature is not defined. Maybe set it to default value
  FEATURE=0
endif
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. Could you also tell me how to check if FEATURE is defined/passed in the first place?

Comment: The make `ifeq` syntax above is wrong.  It should be `ifeq ($(FEATURE),1)` instead.  As for your question, you'll need give more details.  I'm not sure about maditya, but I can't understand what you mean by _how to check if FEATURE is defined/passed in the first place_.

Comment: @MadScientist You're right, I wrote that from memory and messed it up. Will fix. Also I think OP is asking to see whether the variable is set (to any value), for which an `ifdef` ought to work I think

Comment: @maditya That's what I had in mind, I had experimented with ifdef and failed but now I got it.